# How does one create an alpha signal

Tags: returns, factor-models

I am curious and want to do some personal research into alpha signals, but I couldn't find much relevant information. What I think will be the way to is to start with a return series, build a long- short portfolio (e.g. top/bottom decile or some more refined ML techniques), take those returns calculate z-scores and do s.th like

```
z-score * IC * volatility
```

to get a real alpha signal that I can use in a portfolio optimisation context. Would be great to get more insight.

Comment: Generally, the questions of type "How to make money?" are off topic here.

Comment: If the goal is to only understand how to generate an alpha signal in general terms that could be fed in something like Black and Litterman, I thinks its okay. Asking for a method to generate alpha for today's markets? Not so much.

Comment: I am interested in the concept, I thought that's fine as it's a big part of factor research.

Comment: One paper I know that talks about how to incorporate empirical data signals into a portfolio optimisation is Brandt's well known paper on Parametric Portfolio Policies. But I don't think that paper talks about Alpha per se.

Comment: The only 'practical' publication I could find was from MSCI titled 'Converting Scores into Alphas'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to combine factors into an expected return per signal. I then used historical return variances to create a Sharpe-optimized weighted portfolio. In hindsight, I wish I had not used the Sharpe ratio to create the final alpha signal. I believe that more recent work in [Stochastic Portfolio Theory](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1570865908000033) and the [Continuous Kelly Capital Growth Criterion](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9814383139) provides better avenues for maximizing the long-run rate of return for a given amount of risk. I also regret using historical return variances since I think our data contained information that would have been useful in constructing forward-looking covariance matrices.